# Pass different array every time in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am generating comboboxes dynamically and I need to pass a different collection to the ng-repeat every time.How can I do that?

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in $ctrl.inputFilterRows">
    <md-select ng-model="choice.name">
        <md-option ng-repeat="filter in $ctrl.filters" value="{{filter.value}}" >
        {{filter.value}}
       </md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
```

Tried to set from the controller, but didnt work:

```
self.inputFilterRows[0].filters = [{ value: 'June' }, { value: 'July' }, { value: 'August' }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to use `ng-if` on several `md-select` elements and decide which one to enable based on a condition that suits you.

Another is to have a `$scope` variable that is linked to a single `ng-repeat` select, but you keep assigning new values to that $scope variable collection whenever you want. That would force a scope redraw and the `ng-repeat` would now use the new collection values.

Second one is probably cleaner.

EDIT:

Based on a better explanation provided in the comments below I now realise that you want a set of selects, each with their own set of options.

To achieve something like that I would suggest having an array of arrays, in which each object would represent a select, and then it's contents would be the options for that select.

```
$scope.selectArray = [
  { name: 'colours', filters: [{ value: 'black' }, { value: 'red' }, { value: 'blue' }] },
  { name: 'months', filters: [{ value: 'January' }, { value: 'February' }, { value: 'March' }] }
];
```

Now, you can have an `ng-repeat` iterating over `selectArray` (select in selectArrays) to create the selects, and then each one would contain another `ng-repeat` to iterate over the `select.filters` (filter in select.filters)

I am not going to write the exact code because you look like you know what you're doing and I'm sure you can put it together yourself very easily.

If you want to change the dataset of a specific select you can do something like:

```
$scope.selectArray[1].filters[0].value = 'December';
```

or

```
$scope.selectArray[1].filters = [{ value: 'June' }, { value: 'July' }, { value: 'August' }];
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I dynamically generate the scope variable name and link it to the ng-repeat?

Comment: The scope variable name will always be the same. You will just keep assigning different sets of data to it. As an example lets assume $scope.collection, which can start with $scope.collection = A_LIST_OF_COLOURS and then later on $scope.collection = A_LIST_OF_MONTHS. The ng-repeat will always be bound to $scope.collection

Comment: But in this case dont you think that the last assign collection will be the collection for all drop downs because all of them are with the same name. I thought that I need to do something like '<md-option ng-repeat="filter in $ctrl.filters{{$index}}" value="{{filter.value}}" >'

Comment: Oh I was under the impression that you had one select and your ng-repeat was for the options of that. At least that's what your code shows. Do you have 2 ng-repeats? One to create many md-selects and then one for the options of each one?

Comment: Yes, I am adding the combo boxes dynamically. I have two ng-repeats

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your clarifications.

Comment: Thank you. I just dont know how to rename/ access dynamically the inner ng repeat.

Comment: In this case you do not have to change the names. Look at my updated answer

Comment: Thank you. I updated my code to show bought loops. And try to set it but didnt work